# Migrating Extension to Manifest v3

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I want to Migrate My Chrome extension from manifest version 2 to version 3 because in near future Google will remove MV2 extension from their store. For now My extension Manifest code is like this.

```json
{
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "img/icon_active.png",
        "default_popup": "html/popup.html",
        "default_title": "Title here"
    },
    "description": "description here",
    "icons": {
        "128": "img/icon_128.png",
        "16": "img/icon_16.png"
    },
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Title here",
    "version": "1.0.1"
}
```

popup.js file look like this

```js
$(document).on("click", ".copy-me", function(ev) {
    var $body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    var rel = $(this).attr("rel");
    var text = $("#"+rel).text();
    var $tempInput = document.createElement("INPUT");
    $body.appendChild($tempInput);
    $tempInput.setAttribute("value",  text)
    $tempInput.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    $body.removeChild($tempInput);
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Chrome Manifest v2 extensions deprecation timeline**

On **January 17, 2022**: Chrome Web Store no longer accepts new Manifest V2 extensions, however, developers will be allowed to push updates to them.

In **January 2023**: Manifest V2 extensions will stop working and won’t run in Chrome, developers may not be able to push updates to them even with enterprise policy.

[Offical Resource](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/mv2-sunset/)

---

I suggest you read the [Google Chrome Offical Migration Article](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/).

If you don't want to spend your time on this, I suggest [Extension Manifest Converter](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/extension-manifest-converter) which is a tool that open-source and developed by Google.

According to the README file, the tool has limitations:

> This tool aims to simplify the MV3 conversion; it does not fully automate the process. Only search and replace changes are applied to .js files.
>
> This tool does not:
>
> - update any service worker code that relies on a DOM

I tried the tool and it gives me the below output:

```json
{
  "description": "description here",
  "icons": {
    "128": "img/icon_128.png",
    "16": "img/icon_16.png"
  },
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Title here",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "action": {
    "default_icon": "img/icon_active.png",
    "default_popup": "html/popup.html",
    "default_title": "Title here"
  },
  "content_security_policy": {}
}
```

In your case `manifest.json` changed but nothing changed in `popup.js`.